# kind of Master/Slave locking system?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have no clue if the thing I want to do has a name or not.
The "Master/Slave locking system" is sadly the best wording I could come up with.

Now to the problem I have...

Imagine you have the following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Master()
    {

    }

    public void Slave1()
    {

    }

    public void Slave2()
    {

    }
}
```

What I desire is that the slaves methods (Slave1, Slave2) can run parallel in a multi-threading scenario, but when the master (Master) method is called the slaves method shall be blocked from executing while it is executing, additional all currently running slave methods shall run to completion upon entering the master method.

Something like this (with comments):

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Master()
    {
        //block slaves from executing
        //wait for slaves to finish

        //do code...

        //unblock slaves
    }

    public void Slave1()
    {
        //if blocked by master wait, if not execute
        //if currently running when entering master method, let it finish
    }

    public void Slave2()
    {
        //if blocked by master wait, if not execute
        //if currently running when entering master method, let it finish
    }
}
```

I know I could use lock on all 3 methods but than the Slave1 methods will block each other and thats not what I desire.

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly object _syncLock = new object();

    public void Master()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) //blocks Slave1, Slave2
        {
            //run code...
        }
    }

    public void Slave1()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) //blocks Slave2, Master - dont want that
        {
            //run code...
        }
    }

    public void Slave2()
    {
        lock (_syncLock) //blocks Slave1, Master - dont want that
        {
            //run code...
        }
    }
}
```

If possible I would like to have the solution inside this class and not some outside "if you call the methods that way it will do it", the mentioned methods can fire at anytime in a non-ordered way and each method can run muliple times.

Comment: what you are looking for is a multiple reader single writer lock https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock

Comment: Please, have a look at `ReaderWriterLockSlim` (*Master* == *Write*, *Slave* == *Read*; multiple threads for reading or exclusive access for writing) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just have 2 objects you use in the `lock`

Comment: @JeremyThompson can you share some code with 2 objects? I dont see how that is possible with the given problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to put

- Exclusive (Write) lock on `Master()` (no `SlaveN` can run)
- Shared (Read) lock on each `Slave` (you can run another `SlaveN`, but not `Master`)

If it's your case, please, have a look at [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class Foo {
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _syncLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void Master() {
      // Exclusive (write) lock: only Master allowed to run
      _syncLock.EnterWriteLock();

      try {
        //run code...
      }
      finally {
        _syncLock.ExitWriteLock();
      }   
    }

    public void Slave1() {
      // Read lock: you can run Slave2 (with another Read lock), but not Master 
      _syncLock.EnterReadLock();

      try {
        //run code...
      }
      finally {
        _syncLock.ExitReadLock();
      }         
    }

    public void Slave2() {
      // Read lock: you can run Slave1 (with another Read lock), but not Master 
      _syncLock.EnterReadLock();

      try {
        //run code...
      }
      finally {
        _syncLock.ExitReadLock();
      }         
    }   
}
```

Comment: +1 for understanding. :) Just to clarify if I had 2 master methods can I call _syncLock.EnterWriteLock(); twice and block as intended or will it throw exception?

Comment: and will EnterWriteLock wait till all methods have called ExitReadLock ?

Comment: Isn’t this the other way around though? Since master will be blocked from executing until all read locks are released?

Comment: @poke thats what I desire, if the Master() method gets called it should wait till all already running slave methods are done AND block any additionaly slave method till itself is done.

Comment: `_syncLock.EnterWriteLock()` means *provide me exclusive rights*, so one of the `Master`s has to wait; you don't want to wait, may want to use `TryEnterReadLock`/`TryEnterWriteLock` commands.

Comment: @RandRandom Ah, okay, then I misunderstood your question a bit. All right then!

Comment: Another possibility for `Master` is `EnterUpgradeableReadLock()` - so you initially lock the resource in *read* mode, and then if/when you have to get an exclusive access call `_syncLock.EnterWriteLock()`

Comment: @prof1990: multithrtead soft has deadlocking potential... If *two* `Master`s ask for resource, *one* of them gets the resource and another has to wait until 1st one exits the lock; then 2nd `Master` enters the lock. You may have problems if `Master1` *calls* `Master2`